# iPhone sdk handling orientation in uitableview

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uilabel, orientation, uialertview

I am having `UITableView` in my XIB. Now i have two orientation issues in this.

1) I added `UIImageView`, `UILabel` as subviews to `cell.contentview`. Since i need that image and label in each table cell. And for this i defined positions in `CellforRowAtIndexPath`. But when i tried to rotate my view to Landscape, i am getting those images and labels in the same position which i mentioned even when i changed my positions with `WillRotateOrientation`. Why this happens? and How to fix this issue? Here is my code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    imgView1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(680, 60, 40, 40)];
    [imgView1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Downloaded.png"]];

     if([[[appDelegate selectDB] valueForKey:@"bookname"] containsObject:[listOfBooks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] )
      {
         [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView1];
      }
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{

     [self handleInterfaceRotationForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];

if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
{
   imgView1.frame = CGRectMake(890,0, 40, 40);
}
else if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) 
{
   imgView1.frame = CGRectMake(890,0, 40, 40);
}
else if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
{
   imgView1.frame = CGRectMake(690, 60, 40, 40);
}
else 
{
   imgView1.frame = CGRectMake(690, 60, 40, 40);
}
```

// Here i just added the image view code alone.

2) I have an alert view with one progress view and cancel button. When i tried to rotate it from portrait to landscape/landscape to portrait, my alert view is shrieked and am unable to view the progress view and the cancel button automatically getting increased its size.

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView 
{

     if(alertView.tag == kAlertViewOne)
     {
          progressAlert.frame = CGRectMake(270, 380, 300, 200);

              activityView = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]  initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    activityView.frame = CGRectMake(139.0f-18.0f, 40.0f, 37.0f, 37.0f);
    [progressAlert addSubview:activityView];
    [activityView startAnimating];


      DownloadingcancelButton=[(NSMutableArray*)[progressAlert valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0];

      DownloadingcancelButton.frame=CGRectMake(70, 115, 150, 45);

   }
   else if(alertView.tag == kAlertViewTwo)
   {


       UIButton *cancelButton=[(NSMutableArray*)[redownloadAlert valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:1];

       cancelButton.frame=CGRectMake(150, 85, 80, 45);

       UIButton *YESButton=[(NSMutableArray*)[redownloadAlert valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0];

       YESButton.frame=CGRectMake(40, 85, 80, 45);
    }
 }

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration 
{
     [self handleInterfaceRotationForOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];

    if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) 
    {
            progressAlert.frame = CGRectMake(270, 380, 300, 250);
            DownloadingcancelButton.frame=CGRectMake(70, 160, 150, 45);
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) 
    {
           progressAlert.frame = CGRectMake(270, 380, 300, 250);
           DownloadingcancelButton.frame=CGRectMake(70, 160, 150, 45);
    }
    else if (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
    {
           progressAlert.frame = CGRectMake(270, 380, 300, 200);
           DownloadingcancelButton.frame=CGRectMake(70, 115, 150, 45);
    }
    else
    {
           progressAlert.frame = CGRectMake(270, 380, 300, 200);
           DownloadingcancelButton.frame=CGRectMake(70, 115, 150, 45);
    }
```

Simple orientation issue but i struck here for the past one day. Kindly help me out of this. Thanks in advance.